# Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement. React-Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-table

So I'm currently trying to render a table to the page with some data from our backend to show a marketplace of some sort but I seem to be getting this really frustrating error with not much information. I'm struggling to diagnose the issue too. It seems to not be consistent either. it shows most of the time but then sometimes it seems to not show. See the error below:

[image]

Page.tsx

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Card, { CardHeader } from "@/components/global/Card";
import { ILead, IMortgageLead } from "@/interfaces/ILead";
import useAdvisor from "@/context/AdvisorContext";
import { AdvisorStatus } from "@/enums/AdvisorStatus";
import Locked from "@/components/portal/Locked";
import Table, { ExpanderIcon } from "@/components/portal/Table";
import Modal from "@/components/global/Modal";
import SelectField from "@/components/portal/Forms/SelectField";

import { FaBell, FaCoins, FaFilter, FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import InputField from "@/components/portal/Forms/InputField";
import { CellContext, Row } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { trpc } from "@/app/api/_trpc/client";
import { CreditStatus } from "@/enums/CreditStatus";
import { LeadStatus } from "@/enums/LeadStatus";
import InformationIcon from "@/components/global/InformationIcon";
import TableSubComponent from "@/components/portal/Marketplace/TableSubComponent";
import { formatDistance } from "date-fns";
import FilterModal from "@/components/portal/Marketplace/FilterModal";
import ErrorLock from "@/components/portal/ErrorLock";
import PurchaseLead from "@/components/portal/Marketplace/PurchaseLead";

export default function Page() {
  const advisor = useAdvisor();
  const [selectedPurchaseLead, setSelectedPurchaseLead] = React.useState<CellContext<IMortgageLead, any> | null>(null);
  const [openFilters, setOpenFilters] = React.useState(false);
  const [openCreateNotification, setOpenCreateNotification] = React.useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState({
    page: '1',
    page_size: '10',
    ordering: 'any'
  });
  const queryRsp = trpc.leads.getLeads.useQuery(query, {
    refetchIntervalInBackground: false,
    refetchInterval: false,
    keepPreviousData: false,
  });

  if (
    !advisor?.verified ||
    advisor?.status === AdvisorStatus.FLAGGED ||
    advisor?.status === AdvisorStatus.BANNED
  ) {
    return <Locked advisor={advisor} />;
  }

  if (queryRsp.isError) {
    return <ErrorLock />
  }

  if (queryRsp?.data?.count === 0) {
    return <Locked title="No leads available" message="There are currently no leads available for sale, please come back later or ensure you have notifications set to recieve emails for new leads" />
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
    {
      id: "expander",
      header: () => null,
      cell: ({ row }: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <button
            {...{
              onClick:
                row.original.lead_status != "Sold"
                  ? row.getToggleExpandedHandler()
                  : () => null,
              style: {
                cursor: row.original.lead_status != "Sold" ? "pointer" : "not-allowed",
                height: '100%'
              },
            }}
          >
            <ExpanderIcon
              open={row.getIsExpanded()}
              classNames={{
                "bg-red-500": !row.getCanExpand(),
              }}
            />
          </button>
        )
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Mortgage value",
      accessorKey: "mortgage_value",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <>
            {new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
              style: "currency",
              currency: "GBP",
            })
              .format(cell.getValue().replace(',', ''))
              .replace(".00", "")}{" "}
          </>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: "LTV",
      accessorKey: "ltv",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return <>{cell.getValue()}%</>;
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Type",
      accessorKey: "mortgage_type",
    },
    {
      header: "Purpose",
      accessorKey: "purpose",
    },
    {
      header: "Location",
      accessorKey: "location",
    },
    {
      header: "Credit Status",
      accessorKey: "credit_status",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        switch (cell.getValue()) {
          case CreditStatus.UNAVAILABLE:
            return cell.getValue();
          case CreditStatus.BAD:
          case CreditStatus.POOR:
            return <span className={"text-red-500"}>{cell.getValue()}</span>;
          case CreditStatus.FAIR:
            return <span className={"text-yellow-500"}>{cell.getValue()}</span>;
          case CreditStatus.GOOD:
          case CreditStatus.EXCELLENT:
            return <span className={"text-emerald-500"}>{cell.getValue()}</span>;
          default:
            return cell.getValue();
        }
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Qualified",
      accessorKey: "qualified",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <>
            {cell.getValue() ? (
              <span className={"text-green-500"}>Yes</span>
            ) : (
              <span className={"text-red-500"}>No</span>
            )}
          </>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: () => (
        <div className={"flex items-center gap-2"}>
          Deal Stage
          <InformationIcon text={"this is the deal stage"} />
        </div>
      ),
      accessorKey: "qualification_type",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        const array = Array.from(Array(cell.getValue() == 0 ? 1 : cell.getValue()).keys());
        return (
          <div className={"flex gap-1 text-yellow-500"}>
            {array.map((item) => (
              <FaStar key={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Status",
      accessorKey: "status",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        switch (cell.getValue()) {
          case LeadStatus.READY:
            return (
              <span
                className={
                  "block w-full rounded-2xl bg-emerald-500 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold text-white"
                }
              >
                Available
              </span>
            );
          case LeadStatus.SOLD:
          case LeadStatus.EXPIRED:
            return (
              <span
                className={
                  "block w-full rounded-2xl bg-red-500 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold text-white "
                }
              >
                {cell.getValue()}
              </span>
            );
          case LeadStatus.CALLING:
            return (
              <span
                className={
                  "block w-full animate-pulse rounded-2xl bg-deep-sapphire-1000 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold text-white"
                }
              >
                {cell.getValue()}
              </span>
            );
          case LeadStatus.INCOMING:
            return (
              <span
                className={
                  "block w-full animate-pulse rounded-2xl bg-gray-100 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold"
                }
              >
                {cell.getValue()}
              </span>
            );
          default:
            return cell.getValue();
        }
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Generated",
      accessorKey: "created_at",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <span
            className={
              cell.row.original.qualified
                ? "text-emerald-500"
                : "text-deep-sapphire-1000"
            }
          >
            {formatDistance(new Date(cell.getValue()), new Date(), {addSuffix: false})}
          </span>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Notes",
      accessorKey: "notes",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        if (!cell.getValue()) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
          <button
            className={
              "block w-full rounded-2xl bg-yellow-500 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold"
            }
          >
            View notes
          </button>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Price",
      accessorKey: "price",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <div className={"flex items-center gap-2"}>
            <span className={"text-yellow-500"}>
              <FaCoins />
            </span>
            {cell.getValue()}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      header: "Actions",
      cell: (cell: CellContext<IMortgageLead, any>) => {
        return (
          <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setSelectedPurchaseLead(cell)
          }}
            className={
              "block w-full rounded-2xl bg-deep-sapphire-800 px-4 py-2 text-center font-semibold text-white"
            }
          >
            Buy
          </button>
        );
      },
    },
  ], []);

  return (
    <Card
      className={"p-0"}
      title={
        <div className={"flex items-center justify-between"}>
          <CardHeader title={"Leads available for purchase"} />
          <div className={"flex gap-2"}>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenCreateNotification(true);
              }}
              className={
                "flex items-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-100 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-deep-sapphire-1000 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-300 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-gray-300"
              }
            >
              <FaBell /> <span className={"hidden sm:block"}>Notify me</span>
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenFilters(true);
              }}
              className={
                "flex items-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-100 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-deep-sapphire-1000 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-300 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-gray-300"
              }
            >
              <FaFilter /> <span className={"hidden sm:block"}>Filter</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    >
      <Table
        query={queryRsp}
        data={queryRsp?.data ?? null}
        columns={columns}
        getRowCanExpand={(row) => row.original.lead_status != 'Sold'}
        pagination={{
          pageIndex: parseInt(query.page),
          pageSize: parseInt(query.page_size),
        }}
        onPaginationChange={(page) => {
          setQuery({
            ...query,
            page: page.pageIndex.toString(),
            page_size: page.pageSize.toString(),
          });
        }}
        renderSubComponent={({ row }: { row: Row<IMortgageLead> }) => {
          return <TableSubComponent id={row.original.id} />;
        }}
      />

      <Modal open={!!selectedPurchaseLead} onClose={() => {
        setSelectedPurchaseLead(null)
      }} title="Confirm Purchase">
        <PurchaseLead cell={selectedPurchaseLead} closeModal={() => {
          setSelectedPurchaseLead(null);
          queryRsp.refetch();
        }} />
      </Modal>

      <Modal
        open={openCreateNotification}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpenCreateNotification(false);
        }}
        title={"Create a notification"}
      >
        <p>
          Using your filters, we have found 10 leads that match your criteria.
          Would you like to be notified when new leads are available?
        </p>
        <form className={"mt-4 flex flex-col gap-4"}>
          <InputField label={"Name"} placeholder={"Enter a name"} />
          <SelectField
            placeholder={"Select an option"}
            label={"Select how you would like to be notified"}
            options={[]}
          />
          <SelectField
            label={"Select the frequency"}
            placeholder={"Select an option"}
            options={[]}
          />
          <div className={"rounded-xl bg-gray-100 p-4"}>
            <p className={"font-semibold"}>Your selected filters:</p>
            <ul className={"ml-4 list-inside list-disc"}>
              <li>
                <strong>Mortgage Value:</strong> Below £100k
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Loan to Value (LTV):</strong> Below 50%
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Mortgage Purpose:</strong> Remortgage
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Location:</strong> London
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Credit Status:</strong> Good
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Deal Stage:</strong> Early
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div className={"flex items-center justify-end gap-4"}>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setOpenCreateNotification(false);
              }}
              className={
                "rounded-xl bg-gray-100 px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-deep-sapphire-1000 transition-all hover:bg-gray-300"
              }
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setOpenCreateNotification(false);
              }}
              className={
                "rounded-xl bg-niagara-500 px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-white transition-all hover:bg-niagara-600"
              }
            >
              Create
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Modal>
      <FilterModal open={openFilters} onClose={() => {
        setOpenFilters(false)
      }}/>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Table.tsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getExpandedRowModel,
  PaginationState,
  Row,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { ILead, IMortgageLead } from "@/interfaces/ILead";
import { FaCaretLeft, FaCaretRight, FaCaretUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import cnMerge from "@/utils/cnMerge";
import { FaAnglesLeft, FaAnglesRight } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { IPaginatedList } from "@/interfaces/IPaginatedList";
import { UseTRPCQueryResult } from "@trpc/react-query/shared";
import { trpc } from "@/app/api/_trpc/client";

type TableProps<TData> = {
  data: IPaginatedList<TData> | null;
  columns: ColumnDef<TData>[];
  renderSubComponent: (props: { row: Row<TData> }) => React.ReactElement;
  getRowCanExpand: (row: Row<TData>) => boolean;
  onPaginationChange?: (pagination: PaginationState) => void;
  query: UseTRPCQueryResult<any, any>;
  pagination: PaginationState
};

function Table({
  data,
  columns,
  renderSubComponent,
  getRowCanExpand,
  onPaginationChange: _onPaginationChange,
  query,
  pagination: paginationState
}: TableProps<IMortgageLead>): JSX.Element {
  const [{ pageIndex, pageSize }, setPagination] =
    React.useState<PaginationState>({
      pageIndex: paginationState.pageIndex,
      pageSize: paginationState.pageSize,
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    _onPaginationChange?.({ pageIndex, pageSize });
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [pageIndex, pageSize]);

  const pagination = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      pageIndex,
      pageSize,
    }),
    [pageIndex, pageSize],
  );

  const table = useReactTable<IMortgageLead>({
    data: data?.results ?? [],
    columns,
    getRowCanExpand,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    pageCount: Math.ceil((data?.count ?? 0) / pageSize),
    state: {
      pagination,
    },
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    manualPagination: true,
    debugTable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  });

  const { isLoading, error, isError } = query;

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className={"flex h-96 items-center justify-center"}>
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (isError) {
    return (
      <div className={"flex h-96 items-center justify-center"}>
        <p>Error: {error?.message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={"overflow-x-auto"}>
        <table className={"w-full text-xs"}>
          <thead className={"bg-gray-100"}>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <th
                      key={header.id}
                      colSpan={header.colSpan}
                      className={
                        "h-11 whitespace-nowrap border-b border-r px-3 py-2 text-left"
                      }
                    >
                      {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                        <div>
                          {flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext(),
                          )}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </th>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {
              return (
                <Fragment key={row.id}>
                  <tr>
                    {/* first row is a normal row */}
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => {
                      return (
                        <td
                          key={cell.id}
                          className={cnMerge("h-11 border-b border-r px-2", {
                            "m-0 w-11 p-0": cell.column.id === "expander",
                          })}
                        >
                          {flexRender(
                            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                            cell.getContext(),
                          )}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
                  {row.getIsExpanded() && (
                    <tr>
                      {/* 2nd row is a custom 1 cell row */}
                      <td colSpan={row.getVisibleCells().length}>
                        {renderSubComponent({ row })}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )}
                </Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div
        className={
          "flex w-full items-center justify-end gap-4 px-4 py-2 text-sm"
        }
      >
        <div className={"flex gap-2"}>
          <p>Rows per page:</p>
          <select
            className={"m-0 border-0 bg-none p-0"}
            name="pageSize"
            onChange={(e) => {
              table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
            }}
          >
            {[15, 25, 50, 100].map((pageSize) => (
              <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                {pageSize}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex} of{" "}
            {table.getPageCount()}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={"flex gap-2"}>
          <button
            className={
              "flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-100 text-lg text-deep-sapphire-1000 transition-all hover:bg-gray-300 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"
            }
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(0)}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            <FaAnglesLeft />
          </button>
          <button
            className={
              "flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-100 text-lg text-deep-sapphire-1000 transition-all hover:bg-gray-300 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"
            }
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            <FaCaretLeft />
          </button>
          <button
            className={
              "flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-100 text-lg text-deep-sapphire-1000 transition-all hover:bg-gray-300 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"
            }
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            <FaCaretRight />
          </button>
          <button
            className={
              "flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-3xl bg-gray-100 text-lg text-deep-sapphire-1000 transition-all hover:bg-gray-300 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"
            }
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(table.getPageCount() - 1)}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            <FaAnglesRight />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export function ExpanderIcon({
  open = false,
  classNames = {},
}: {
  open: boolean;
  classNames?: { [key: string]: boolean };
}): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <span
      className={cnMerge(
        "flex h-11 w-11 items-center justify-center bg-emerald-500 text-2xl text-white h-full",
        {
          "bg-emerald-600": open,
          "bg-emerald-500": !open,
          ...classNames,
        },
      )}
    >
      <FaCaretUp
        className={cnMerge("origin-center transform transition-all", {
          "rotate-180": open,
          "rotate-90": !open,
        })}
      />
    </span>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Those are the 3 components that are used on those pages with any form of logic to cause this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this?

I currently use TRPC to get the data from the backend to the frontend and TanStack React Table to display the tables

Thanks in advance

I have tried almost everything when it comes to trying to resolve this barring physically rewriting the code.

I fear it could be due to me passing the query through as a prop to the table to allow me to refetch on some certain table actions

Comment: You have `const columns = React.useMemo(() => [`  after ->  `if (......) return`    You can't do that.  All hooks have to run in the same order on every re-render.

Comment: You added `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` so eslint wouldn't complain about the problem you are now having.